# Fastest Way To Find Last Names From String in R

Tags: r, string, match, grepl

I am trying to identify likely last name from parts of name strings in various formats in R. What is the fastest way to identify the longest string match from the dataset of last names to a given name string (I'm using the wru surnames2010 dataset)?

I need the longest possibility rather than any possibility. I.e. in the example below the first string "scottcampbell" contains possible surnames "scott" and "campbell".  I want to only return the longest of the possible matches, in this case only "campbell".

**Reproduce example data:**

```
library(wru)
data("surnames2010")
#filter out names under 4 characters
lnames <- surnames2010[nchar(as.character(surnames2010$surname))>3,]
testvec <- c("scottcampbell","mattbaker","tsmith","watkins","burnsmary","terri","frankrodriguez","neal")
```

**Desired imagined function+result:**

```
foo_longest_matches(testvec)
#Desired imagined result:
[1] "campbell" "baker" "smith" "watkins" "burns" "terri" "rodriguez" "neal")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `adist`. Please note that you are doing more than 1million comparisons to obtain the longest. I would prefer you use a different method. The best so far that I have in mind is

```
a <- adist(toupper(testvec), surnames2010$surname, counts = TRUE)
b <- attr(a, "trafos")
d <- array(grepl("S|I", b) + nchar(gsub("(.)\\1++", "1",b, perl=TRUE)), dim(a)) * 10 + a
as.character(surnames2010$surname[max.col(-d)])
[1] "CAMPBELL"  "BAKER"     "SMITH"     "WATKINS"   "BURNS"     "TERRI"     "RODRIGUEZ" "NEAL"
```

benchmark:

```
longest <- function(testvec,namevec){
  a <- adist(testvec, namevec, counts = TRUE)
  b <- attr(a, "trafos")
  d <- array(grepl("S|I", b) + nchar(gsub("(.)\\1++", "1",b, perl=TRUE)), dim(a)) * 10 + a
  as.character(namevec[max.col(-d)])
}
```

EDIT: Was able to obtain a faster method(Not necessarily the fastest)

```
longest2 <- function(testvec,namevec){
  a <- stack(sapply(namevec,grep,testvec,value = TRUE,simplify = FALSE))
  tapply(as.character(a[, 2]), a[, 1], function(x) x[which.max(nchar(x))])[testvec]
}


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(longest(testvec,lnames$surname),longest2(testvec,lnames$surname),foo_longest_matches(testvec),times = 5)
Unit: seconds
                              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  longest(testvec, lnames$surname)  3.316550  3.984128  5.308339  6.265192  6.396348  6.579477     5
 longest2(testvec, lnames$surname)  1.817059  1.917883  2.835354  3.350068  3.538278  3.553481     5
      foo_longest_matches(testvec) 10.093179 10.325489 11.610619 10.756714 10.889326 15.988384     5
```

Comment: Is there a way to ensure the output is the same length as the input testvec?

Comment: @NealBarsch The output will be the same length as the input

Comment: Not in every case. Use ``testvec <- c("nomatch","scottcampbell","mattbaker","tsmith","watkins","burnsmary","terri","frankrodriguez","neal","nomatch")`` In this case the output for function ``length(longest2(testvec,lnames$surname))=9``  when input ``length(testvec)=11``

Comment: @NealBarsch. It seams `longest2` has some technicalities. Use `longest` instead

Comment: @NealBarsch. Have editted `longest2`. You can now use it.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about fastest but here is a method to test:

```
library(wru)
data("surnames2010")
lnames <- surnames2010[nchar(as.character(surnames2010$surname))>3,]
testvec <- c("scottcampbell","mattbaker","tsmith","watkins","burnsmary","terri","frankrodriguez","neal")

lnames$surname <- tolower(lnames$surname)
testvec <- tolower(testvec)

foo_longest_matches <- function(string_vector) {
  outdf <- c()
  for (name in string_vector) {
    print(name)
    ting <- lnames[sapply(lnames$surname, function(x) grepl(x, name)),]
    # you only care about the longest, remove the next line to get all matches
    ting <- ting[which.max(nchar(ting$surname)),]
    outdf <- rbind(outdf, ting)
  }
  return(outdf)
}

get_matches <- foo_longest_matches(testvec)
get_matches
#          surname  p_whi  p_bla      p_his      p_asi      p_oth
# 47      campbell 0.7366 0.2047 0.02490000 0.00530000 0.02840000
# 44         baker 0.7983 0.1444 0.02280000 0.00560000 0.02890000
# 1          smith 0.7090 0.2311 0.02400000 0.00500000 0.03080000
# 240      watkins 0.6203 0.3227 0.02090000 0.00420000 0.03200000
# 155        burns 0.8026 0.1406 0.02480000 0.00590000 0.02610000
# 110133     terri 0.7453 0.1801 0.01243333 0.01243333 0.04973333
# 9      rodriguez 0.0475 0.0054 0.93770000 0.00570000 0.00360000
# 337         neal 0.6210 0.3184 0.02160000 0.00600000 0.03290000
```

Comment: first, `nchar` is vectorized. Do `which.max(nchar(ting$surname))`